# Stationary distribution of a "birth-death model" that does not have Markov property

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, mathematical-modeling, markov-process

A typical birth-death process is defined such as the probability of going from any state $j$ to any state $i$ is given by:

$$
      p_{ij}=  \begin{cases}
        b_i & \text {if  $j = i+1$} \\
        d_i & \text {if  $j = i-1$} \\
        1 - b_i - d_i & \text {if $j = i$} \\
        0 & \text {otherwise}\\
        \end{cases}
$$

Therefore the transition matrix is:

$$
      M=  \left(\begin{matrix}
        1-b_o & d_1 & 0 & … & 0 \\
        b_0 & 1 - b_1 - d_1 & d_2 & … & 0 \\
        0 & b_1 & 1 - b_2 - d_2 & … & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & … & 1-d_m\\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Then, one can find the stationary distribution by seeking the vector $\overrightarrow  \pi$ that solves:

$$(I-M)\overrightarrow  \pi = \overrightarrow  0$$

,where $\overrightarrow  0$ is a vector of zeros and $I$ is the identity matrix.

**Question**

If we **do not respect the Markov property** and every $b_i$ and $d_i$ are functions of $t$ ($b(i,t)$ and $d(i,t)$). Then, **how can we calculate the stationary distribution of this pseudo-birth-death model?**

In order to make sure there is a stationary distribution, I am suggesting to modify the above matrix so that when the system enters in one of the two extreme cases, it stays there forever.

$$
      M=  \left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & d_1 & 0 & … & 0 \\
        0 & 1 - b_1 - d_1 & d_2 & … & 0 \\
        0 & b_1 & 1 - b_2 - d_2 & … & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & … & 1\\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

---

As an example where $b_i$ and $d_i$ are actually functions of $t$, one can consider:

- $b_{it} = C_b^{\space t}$ (or $b(i,t) = C_b^{\space t}$ if you prefer) and $d_{it} = C_d^{\space t}$, where $C_b$ and $C_d$ are constant terms.
- (The recurrence relation would be $b_{it} = b_{it-1} \cdot C_b$ or $b(i,t)=b(i,t-1) \cdot C_b$ if you prefer)

Comment: What makes you think there will be a stationary distribution if birth and death rates can vary over time?

Comment: @Henry Yes, you're right. I'll made a little modification in the model so that it fits better my needs. Now, with the modifciations, when the system reaches one of the two extreme states, it stays there forever. So that the stationary distribution can give the probability of reaching one states over the probability of reaching the other one.